# lws_write will change the row source buffer?

Tags: c, libwebsockets

I tried send data by lws_write, but I find the buffer has been changed when it returns.

```
INFO("Now write head data %d",n);
lwsl_hexdump_notice(pstPosTmp->data, pstPosTmp->len);
n = lws_write(wsi,pstPosTmp->data + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING,pstPosTmp->len,LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
INFO("Now write payload data %d %p %s ",n,pstPosTmp->data,(char *)(pstPosTmp->data + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING));
lwsl_hexdump_notice(pstPosTmp->data, pstPosTmp->len);
```

the twice lwsl_hexdump_notice will show different content.

Comment: The protocol header is written into the PRE area of the buffer - this is documented. It should not overwrite your data, though.